# Nginx- compressing Content-Type -application/octet;charset=UTF-8

Tags: nginx, compression, nginx-config

So I'm using an api where the response content type is: application/octet;charset=UTF-8, and I'm trying to compress it to gzip through nginx.
I could only find references to application/octet-stream.
this content type is not a part of the mime-types so there needs to be another solution which I can't find.

this is most of my nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    # Proxy configurations (for tomcat)
    include conf.d/*.conf;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    charset                utf-8;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types application/json application/jsonx application/octet;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    

}
```

I even tried `gzip_types */*;` but it didn't work as well

those are the headers of the response:

```
Server: nginx/1.23.1
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2022 09:04:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: USER_ID, CLIENT_VERSION, Admin-Signature, App-Type
SERVER_SEND_TIME: 2022-08-29T09:04:42.753
```

how can I compress this response?
thanks

Comment: is application/octet a valid content type?
I do not see it listed here.
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: it's a custom content type for a binary response the my company uses
@KshitijJoshi